# kotlin RecyclerView Pagination

Tags: android, pagination, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to make my `RecyclerView` load only 10 items and load more 10 after scrolling and work like this.
I was add the items in array using `Volley`.
Here is my `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
class newsAdapter constructor(private val activety:MainActivity, private val ListOfCash:ArrayList<newsModling>,
                          val listener:BTNListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<newsAdapter.ViewHolder>(),BTNListener {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = ListOfCash.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_tick, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(ListOfCash[position], listener, ListOfCash)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(Data: newsModling, listener: BTNListener, listOfnew: ArrayList<newsModling>) {
            var ListOfnewsin = listOfnew[adapterPosition]

            var newstitle = ListOfnewsin.title
            var newsdate = ListOfnewsin.date

            itemView.newsDate.text = newsdate
            itemView.newsTitle.text = newstitle

            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                //var cashSTR = cashNumIn.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know, what I must use or where I will type it.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/ and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/index.html#0

Comment: [3 Android RecyclerView Load More On Scroll Examples](https://androidride.com/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-example/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using this scroll listener with your `recyclerview`.

In load more items place your logic to load more items.

`isLastPage` will return true if there are no items to load.

`isLoading` will be true while you are fetching data and false when you have fetched the data.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

/**
 * Pagination class to add more items to the list when reach the last item.
 */
abstract class PaginationScrollListener
/**
 * Supporting only LinearLayoutManager for now.
 *
 * @param layoutManager
 */
(var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    abstract fun isLastPage(): Boolean

    abstract fun isLoading(): Boolean

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
        val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
        val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

        if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
            if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                loadMoreItems()
            }//                    && totalItemCount >= ClothesFragment.itemsCount
        }
    }
    abstract fun loadMoreItems()
}
```

Add this to your `recyclerview`

```
var isLastPage: Boolean = false
var isLoading: Boolean = false

recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(object : PaginationScrollListener(your_layoutManager) {
    override fun isLastPage(): Boolean {
        return isLastPage
    }

    override fun isLoading(): Boolean {
        return isLoading
    }

    override fun loadMoreItems() {
        isLoading = true
        //you have to call loadmore items to get more data 
        getMoreItems()
    }
})    

fun getMoreItems() {
    //after fetching your data assuming you have fetched list in your 
    // recyclerview adapter assuming your recyclerview adapter is 
    //rvAdapter
    after getting your data you have to assign false to isLoading 
    isLoading = false    

    rvAdapter.addData(list)
}
```

Now in your `recyclerview` adapter add the following method.

Here the list is the list which feeds your `recyclerview` in your Adapter.
Make sure you initialize the list in your `recyclerview`.

```
fun addData(listItems: ArrayList<yourObject>) {
    var size = this.listItems.size
    this.listItems.addAll(listItems)
    var sizeNew = this.listItems.size
    notifyItemRangeChanged(size, sizeNew)
}
```

Comment: you can convert it in kotlin by using ctrl+shift+altr+k in android studio if you want I can give you the kotlin one

Comment: Please if you can

Comment: thank you at all but i still dont know hot to sed (var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() to the constructor from recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener

Comment: i mean what i will type in (your_layoutManager)

Comment: I do it but not working talk to me in whatsapp pleas

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var results = mutableListOf<MovieDetails>()
    lateinit var adapter: MovieAdapter
    private var pageNum = 1
    var page = -1
    var isLoading = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        adapter = MovieAdapter(this@MainActivity, results)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager
        getMovies()

        // RecyclerView Pagination********************************
        recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
                val pastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                val total = adapter.itemCount

                if (!isLoading) {

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItem) >= total) {
                        pageNum++
                        getMovies()
                    }
                }
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }
        })


    }

    private fun getMovies() {
        val movie: Call<Movies> = MovieService.movieInstance.getTrending(pageNum)
        movie.enqueue(object : Callback<Movies> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Movies>, response: Response<Movies>) {
                val m = response.body()
                if (m != null) {
                    page = m.page
                    results.addAll(m.results)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Movies>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst new answers to old questions are welcome, it would be much better if you could [edit] your answer and add an explanation as to how your code solves the problem in a way that is better/different to the accepted answer.