# How to modify the item count of recycleviewer when the end of the last is reached?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am looking to modify the number of items that is displayed in my recyclerviewer on the event that the last item of the current itemcount is viewed..

```
   var mainadapt = MainAdapter()
        Timeline.adapter = mainadapt
        
        fun OnLastItemReached(){
            Timeline.adapter.itemCount += 10
        }
```

The code above is incorrect since the method
".itemcount" isn't a class variable so it can't just be modified at will. But it is the logic that I am trying to showcase, Basically loading 10 more items every time the last items is viewed.

Comment: i can help you with java not kotlin(if you want) you can convert it into java then

Comment: please , i would very much appreciate it. can I messenger you?

Comment: before that tell me what you exactly want in breaf. are trying to do manual pagination with Adapter?

Comment: yes , im trying to just load more items into recycleviewer when the last item is reached.. like if create a class variable inside of my adapter class : var itemcountvar = 20

Comment: when the position of the onbindviewholder = 20 i will load 10 more

Comment: this way it isn't too many items being created at once.

Comment: Add a scroll listener to the layout manager, inside the layout manager has a method for knowing the las visible item, also you can get the position of it, so it is basically: is last visible item position is greater than the adapter item count minus yout threshold then add more items

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin RecyclerView Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433106/kotlin-recyclerview-pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer i am giving you in Java as you r requested in comment

use `getItemCount` like this and call `loadPage` page method from responsible `Activity` or `Fragment` with page number

```
int initialSize =20;
int loadSize=10;
int pageNumber =1;
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (infos.size()<initialSize){
        return infos.size();
    }
    else if (infos.size()>initialSize+(pageNumber*loadSize)){
        return initialSize+(pageNumber*loadSize);
    }else {
        return infos.size();
    }
   
}

public void loadPage(int page){
    pageNumber =page;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: im really just trying to have a class variable, and then have that class variable the return value for the getitemcount() , I can't find a way to modify the class variable , unless its from where the object was initilized , which is the class linked to the activity.

Comment: you can call `loadPage` from `onBindViewHolder` when the last position binds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728909/12676247 you can get that from here

Comment: recreate means starting the activity from beginning so everything under that activity will start from biginng